# PCA for RGB images

Tags: opencv, pca

I'm trying do PCA on RGB images. What I found is I can first split the image into three channels and then perform PCA on each channel and lastly combine again three of them. But the problem is I don't know how to combine back the channels. Is there anyway using opencv to combine the channels back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging three grayscale \[R, G, B\] images into a single color image in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821253/merging-three-grayscale-r-g-b-images-into-a-single-color-image-in-opencv)

Comment: [`merge`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga7d7b4d6c6ee504b30a20b1680029c7b4)

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. The point of PCA is (IMHO) to find the axis of greatest variance amongst multiple correlated bands to reduce the dimensionality of say, multi-spectral data. Why/how would you try and do that with a single band/channel?